# What causes this union all function to stop working?

Tags: mysql

```
  SELECT distinct RESTAURANT, RANK, 
  (select avg(SCORE) 
  from TRIPADVISOR 
  where rank<=10 and rank>=0) as top10
  FROM TRIPADVISOR 
  ORDER BY RANK LIMIT 10   

  union all

  SELECT distinct RESTAURANT, RANK, 
  (select avg(SCORE) 
  from TRIPADVISOR 
  where rank<=249 and rank>=57) as bottom10
  FROM TRIPADVISOR 
  ORDER BY RANK DESC LIMIT 10
```

I have a quick question I wanted to ask. As you can see above, I have two queries in the same table that I want to union all. I am new to sql, so majority of the functions and aggregate, I am not familiar with. Here is the dilemma. I have a TRIPADVISOR table that consists of restaurant column which is the name of the restaurant, rank column which is the trip advisor rank, and score column. For the first query, I was able to successfully get the average of the scores for the top 10 ranking of TripAdvisor. For the bottom, its the bottom 10 ranking. The problem, I am having is to combine these two average results in one query. I had the first one in one query tab and second one in another query tab. I just had copied the second query into the first query and inserted union all. I am using mysqlworkbench . The error its giving me is: union is not valid at this position, expecting: EOF 
:','. Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you move the ) as top10 after the order by?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose queries in `()` if you want to use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clauses that apply to the individual queries in a `UNION` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)):

```
  (SELECT distinct RESTAURANT, RANK, 
  (select avg(SCORE) 
  from TRIPADVISOR 
  where rank<=10 and rank>=0) as top10
  FROM TRIPADVISOR 
  ORDER BY RANK LIMIT 10)  

  union all

  (SELECT distinct RESTAURANT, RANK, 
  (select avg(SCORE) 
  from TRIPADVISOR 
  where rank<=249 and rank>=57) as bottom10
  FROM TRIPADVISOR 
  ORDER BY RANK DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: Incorrect. See this example: SELECT fname, lname, addr FROM prospect
-> UNION ALL
-> SELECT first_name, last_name, address FROM customer
-> UNION
-> SELECT company, '', street FROM vendor; Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-union-keyword.htm

Comment: @LajosArpad from the manual: "To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT"

Comment: Then you should edit your answer and explain that the () parantheses are needed because of the order by. Your answer can be understood as if one would have to use paranthese in order to union. This is why I misunderstood it. Please, edit it and let me know when it's done.

Comment: @LajosArpad You are correct I should have given more explanation to the answer. I have done so now.